# Is it normal to not be indexed in Google after a month?

Tags: seo, google, google-index

I started 2 new sites at pretty much the same time.  They are both small blogs, running the exact same blogging software (even the same template).  The content is different, of course.

One of them was indexed in Google 3 days after launch.  The other one has not been indexed at all.  It gets visited by Googlebot 1-2 times a week, but it won't show up in search results, even if I do a "site:www.example.com" search.

Is this normal?

Comment: It varies, please check out the linked post and follow through what other members suggest. Additional many more posts such as yours can be found on the site already.

Comment: Linked post does not help; everything that is mentioned there I have already checked.  (Which you would have seen if you had read my question instead of just marking it as duplicate.)

Comment: I read your question, there wasn't much to read. The linked question is a catch all which is intended to question reasons why you're site may not be index, if you can't find an answer then its because no one has left one yet and this doesn't merit a whole new question formed based purely for your site. If you would like further assistance I recommend you link your site in our Chat channel where we have members regularly check throughout the day, without linking your site it could many reasons why your site is not indexing and advice given would be purely guesses.

Comment: There other thing could be that Google just hasn't indexed it and therefor no answer, Google can take many crawls before it decides to actually index pages. Again, I'll be happily to continue this conversation in chat.